# Is there a way to control tile texture mapping, while keeping the original material scale?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I am tiling a bathroom and I've had to change the mapping from generated to UV so I could move the texture, to align the white lines between the faces (where the creases are).

Is this the correct way to approach this or am I doing it wrong?

The original generated mapping brick texture:

[image]

For the other parts of the tile surface I have added some other meshes with the same material. The 2 front large faces of the shower have the original size that I got from generated mapping. The other parts are UV unwrapped, but the issue is that I am losing the scale:

[image]

I could do it manually but that doesn't seem the smartest or correct way to do this

Do I have to make all of these as 1 mesh? Can they stay separate like this? Because all these planes have a .5cm solidify mod for some distance from the wall

Comment: What do you mean by "can they stay separate"? You can unwrap with the Smart UV Project mode for example, then move the UVs in the UV Editor until the lines match the angles

Comment: Hi Alex :). To keep the texture size across multiple objects, you need to keep the same texel density. With addons it's very simple [Texel Density Checker Addon](https://mrven.gumroad.com/l/CEIOR)

Comment: @moonboots I meant if they can stay as separate meshes or do I have to join them and then unwrap it

Comment: Sure you can join all these meshes into one object and even merge their vertices, when you'll unwrap the UVs can be separate

Comment: Do I have to join them?

Comment: You don't have to, but if you have no reason to keep them separate it's more convenient to have one object

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have this object with this brick texture, I've unwrapped all at once with the *Smart UV Project* mode, the size of the brick is homogeneous:

[image]

Then I can move the UVs to adjust the texture if necessary:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Had you applied the rotation (ctrl+a > rotation)? These walls looks like separated objects and maybe it could be that simple.

Comment: they are separate, but applying the rotation makes no difference.